# collection of random strings, and every string with random characters (java)

Tags: java, string, random

I need to write a method that generates a random collection of strings, each of which is a string that contains from 6 to 15 characters long. The number of strings in the collection is passed as a parameter to the method.
I think that strings should have different characters.

I tried, but there is a mistake in something. The collection gives the same count of strings and the same count of characters in every string. And the quantity of characters in a string conforms to the number of characters. I change `int len` on 5 for example then I receive 5 strings in a collection and 5 characters in a string.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(generateRandomString(5, 5));
}

public static String generateRandomString(int len, int count) {
    String letters = new String("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
    StringBuffer word = new StringBuffer();
    List<StringBuffer> randomWords = new LinkedList<StringBuffer>();

    int randomIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        randomIndex = new Random().nextInt(letters.length());
        word.append(letters.charAt(randomIndex));
        for (int j = 0; j < randomWords.size() && j <= count; j++);
        randomWords.add(word);
    }
    return randomWords.toString();
}
```

In console:

```
[kdvjw, kdvjw, kdvjw, kdvjw, kdvjw]
```

Comment: For any one call, are all the generated strings supposed to have the same length?

Comment: I think generated strings can have the different length and it will be more interestihg. But if it will be the same it will not be a mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that returns a collection of random strings of different lengths that vary between given limits:

```
private static final String letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

public static String generateRandomString(int lower, int upper, int count) {
    final List<StringBuilder> randomWords = new ArrayList<>(count);
    final Random random = new Random();
    final int range = upper - lower + 1;

    while (--count >= 0) {
        int wordLength = lower + random.nextInt(range);
        final StringBuilder word = new StringBuilder(wordLength);

        while (--wordLength >= 0) {
            word.append(letters.charAt(random.nextInt(letters.length())));
        }
        randomWords.add(word);
    }
    return randomWords.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Random strings of different lengths will be perfect.
But it has a problem with adding the word to List<StringBuffer> randomWords, because the word has a StringBuilder type:

word.append(letters.charAt(random.nextInt(letters.length())));
             randomWords.add(word);

Comment: @YanaKit - Oops. The declaration of `randomWords` was wrong. I just updated it to be `List<StringBuilder>` instead of `List<StringBuffer>`.

Comment: Thanks once more! I've tryed it and now it works. But it gave me this result: http://prntscr.com/lpqimp

Comment: @YanaKit - What result?

Comment: For example: [nctph, nctph, nctph, nctph, nctph, wchk, wchk, wchk, wchk] or [dms, dms, dms, qonglg, qonglg, qonglg, qonglg, qonglg, qonglg]. Maybe it's right. I thought every word will be with random chars or not?

Comment: I found what I need to do. I changed List to HashSet and now it works perfect: all words are unique. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @YanaKit - I had the call to `randomWords.add(word)` in the wrong place. Now that I've moved it, the whole thing should work with a `List` as well as with a `Set`.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment you are adding the same reference to `word` to the `List` over and over again. This will make it so that you'll end up with a `List` of references to the same object.

Also you have a semicolon at the end of your `for` loop, and your loops are a little messed up. Right now you are adding `word` to every index of the `List` on every iteration of the outer loop. Instead, loop for as many `Strings` you want to return, and in the inner loop append onto the `StringBuffer`.

Also I would recommend making your `Random` object outside of the loop, so that a new one is not created on every iteration:

```
public static String generateRandomString(int len, int count) {
    String letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";    
    Random rand = new Random();
    List<StringBuffer> randomWords = new LinkedList<StringBuffer>();
    int randomIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {

        StringBuffer word = new StringBuffer();
        for (int j = 0; j <= len; j++) {
            randomIndex = rand.nextInt(letters.length());
            word.append(letters.charAt(randomIndex));
        }
        randomWords.add(word);
    }
    return randomWords.toString();
}
```

***Sample Output:***

```
[oumcmb, vuovbx, sdysoo, aqxbxc, oijmmh]
```

---

Also just to note Apache Commons has a [`RandomStringUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/RandomStringUtils.html) class which has a method to generate a random `String` of given length.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to incapsulate this logic into separate class.

```
public final class RandomString {

    private static final char[] SYMBOLS = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();

    private final Random random = new Random();

    public String nextString(int len) {
        StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(len);

        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            buf.append(SYMBOLS[random.nextInt(SYMBOLS.length)]);

        return buf.toString();
    }
}
```

An use it where you need:

```
public static Set<String> generateRandomString(int len, int count) {
    RandomString randomString = new RandomString();

    Set<String> res = new HashSet<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        res.add(randomString.nextString(len));

    return res;
}
```